# Python script doesn't fully run from Qt

Tags: python, c++, qt

I want to run a python script from Qt. I am able to call it with `QProcess` and get `qDebug()` to print what the python script prints. But for some reason I can't Qt to read any of the python script's prints after a certain point in the code.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thank you so much in advance. This is my first question here so I'm sorry if I did something wrong.

My widget.cpp file and python script are below. (The python script is in the Qt program's directory.)

My widget.cpp file:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include "QDebug"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDir>


Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(checkTexts()));
    timer->start(5000);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}


void Widget::checkTexts()
{
    //QProcess process; //I also tried this way with the same results
    QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);

    QStringList arguments { QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/../../../../../Folder/Qt Desktop Application/ApplicationFiles/PullText.py"};

    process->start("python", arguments);
    process->waitForFinished(-1);

    QString output = process->readAll();
    process->close();
    qDebug() << output;
}
```

My Python script (PullText.py) which is supposed to send one line of a text file to my Qt application:

```
newMessageSplitter = "***\n"

#print "1" #this prints in the qDebug() << output

file = open("texts.txt","r")

#print “2” #this doesn't print

texts = file.read()

x = texts.find(newMessageSplitter) + len(newMessageSplitter)
singleLine = texts[:x-len(newMessageSplitter)]
file.close()
file = open("texts.txt","w")
file.write(texts[x:])
file.close()

#print singleLine #this is what I want to send to the output but it doesn't get sent to Qt
```

Comment: If you manually run the python script, does it work? If it errors out before the second print, you will not see that output

Comment: `file.close` or `file.close()`?

Comment: The python script runs correctly when I run it alone. And sorry, the file.close thing was a typo in my question.

Comment: @Johnny 
It was the only typographical error? I suppose there are no more errors of that type since they cause boredom, and we are reluctant to help you, you could indicate the relationship between the routes of your project, the build folder and your .py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
process->waitForFinished(-1);
```

Calling `waitForFinished()` is problematic if your child process produces more than a small amount of output, because if your child process's `stdout` output buffer fills up, you have a deadlock situation:  the child/Python process is now blocked waiting for the buffer to drain so that it can write more output into it; meanwhile, your Qt/parent process is also blocked, waiting for the child process to exit.

Since neither process can do anything, the child process will never exit, therefore `waitForFinished()` will never return, and your program is stuck forever.

(The other possibility is that the child process is set to simply discard any additional output text when its `stdout` buffer fills up; in which case the child process will exit and `waitForFinished()` will return, but your `process->readAll()` call will only return the initial output-text that was able to fit into the output-buffer; the remaining text was discarded so your Qt process never gets to see it)

In either case, the solution is not to wait inside `waitForFinished()`, but rather to just call `readAll()` immediately to gather its output without waiting.  You may need to call it in a loop until the child process has exited, possibly along with `waitForReadyRead()` to avoid busy-looping.

Comment: I tried this `process->start("python", arguments);
    while(true){
        process->waitForFinished();
        QString output = process->readAll();
        if(output != ""){
            qDebug() << output;
        }
    }` and it just prints "1\n" once and then nothing. It gets the first output but it's as though the python script stops being able to send its output to Qt once `file = open("texts.txt","r")` runs. When I run the python script alone I get all of the print statements.

Comment: Try replacing the "texts.txt" with the full path name (e.g. "/Users/Johnny/Documents/texts.txt" or whatever it is for that file) and see if that works better.  If so, then the problem is that your Qt application's current directory is different from the directory where texts.txt is, and so the open() command is failing.

Comment: Replacing "texts.txt" with the full path name fixed it! Thank you so much.